# triple integration in python where the limits depend on some variables

Tags: python, scipy

How can I solve this integral in python? The following codes did not work. thx

[image]

```
import scipy.integrate as spi
import numpy as np

integrand = lambda s, t1, t2: (0.07 * s**2 / (1+0.07*s**3)) + (0.08 * s**2 / (1+0.8*s**2))

t2min = lambda t1, t2: 0.
t2max = lambda t1, t2: np.inf

t1min = lambda s: 0.
t1max = lambda s: t2

smin = lambda t1: t1
smax = lambda t2: t2

result = spi.tplquad(integrand, t2min, t2max, t1min, t1max, smin, smax)
```

Answer (score 0):

Limit the boundary.

```
t2_max = 100000000;
accm=0
for t1 in range(t2_max):
    for t2 in range(t1):
        tmp = 0;
        for s in range(t1, t2): 
            tmp += "function(s)"
        accm += np.exp(-tmp)
```